# Login failure after 20.04 update

Tags: updates, login, password, 20.04

I had a problem logging on after an update of 20.04

I had Auto-Login enabled

The Login screen would not let me logon to the desktop. I was in an endless loop.

I searched Askubuntu everywhere.

Luckily I happened to find:
Ubuntu Focal Fossa (20.04) LTS is now released, and posts about it are (generally) No Longer Offtopic

In the comments section I came across:
Nvidia + Auto Login - If you have an Nvidia card and install the driver (during the initial ISO setup) or upgrade from 19.10 or 18.04, and during this time, you either had Auto-Login enabled or set it up during the ISO setup), then you will encounter an issue where the Login screen won't let you log to the desktop. You will end up in a infinite loop. The issues is mentioned in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1845801
etc

Luis Alvarado answered Apr 26 at 6:12

This guy is brilliant but the solution is hidden.

My post is to make it visible to everyone with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my logon failure was due (believe it or not) to my having a Nvidia graphics card. Probably the case for millions of Ubuntu users.

The answer in my case was to disable auto-login.

Comment: Please return in 48 hours to accept your own answer.